# sql order by not working with decimal(18,6)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

The SQL query with `order by` clause is not working properly.

Query:

```
select cast(actual_qty as decimal(18,2)) from `Bin`
        where warehouse = `Warehouse`.name
        order by actual_qty desc
```

Output of above query:

```
303.00
550.00
0.00
3.00
```

The type of `actual_qty` is `decimal(18,6)`. I tried using `cast` function in order by, didn't work.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Update1:

Here's my full query that is being fired:

```
select `tabWarehouse`.name, CONCAT_WS(" : ", "Actual Qty", ifnull( ( select round(`tabBin`.actual_qty, 2) as qty
from `tabBin` where `tabBin`.warehouse = `tabWarehouse`.name
and `tabBin`.item_code = '30440'
order by qty desc), 0) ) as actual_qty
from `tabWarehouse` where `tabWarehouse`.`name` like '%%%%' and ifnull(`tabWarehouse`.company, '') in ('', 'TILE TEST') and `tabWarehouse`.is_group = 0.0
limit 0, 20
```

The output is still the same which is not really ordered by the qty in a descending manner.

Update 2:

This is how my code looks:

```
    query = """select tw.name,
        CONCAT_WS(" : ", "Actual Qty", ifnull(round(`tabBin`.actual_qty, 2), 0 ) actual_qty
        from `tabWarehouse` tw left join `tabBin` tb
        on tb.warehouse = tw.name {bin_conditions}
        where
           tw.`{key}` like {txt}
            {fcond} {mcond}
        order by ifnull(round(tb.actual_qty, 2), 0) desc
        limit
            {start}, {page_len}
        """.format(
            bin_conditions=get_filters_cond(doctype, filter_dict.get("Bin"),bin_conditions, ignore_permissions=True),
            # sub_query=sub_query,
            key=searchfield,
            fcond=get_filters_cond(doctype, filter_dict.get("Warehouse"), conditions),
            mcond=get_match_cond(doctype),
            start=start,
            page_len=page_len,
            txt=frappe.db.escape('%{0}%'.format(txt))
        )
```

Comment: If the data type of actual_qty is decimal(18,2) why do you cast it?

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle,because this should work https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba167f73f0593ee96cb3770775cfc50a

Comment: @forpas I was doing rounding there previously but shared the code while I was playing around with the query. I have no experience with sql. I just updated my question, can you take a look?

Comment: There is no update in your question.

Comment: @forpas there is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ORDER BY clause in your query.
The ORDER BY inside the correlated subquery is useless because that subquery will work only if it returns only 1 row and does not effect the final results.
Try this:

```
select tw.name, 
       CONCAT_WS(" : ", "Actual Qty", ifnull(round(tb.actual_qty, 2), 0)) actual_qty
from tabWarehouse tw left join tabBin tb
on tb.warehouse = tw.name and tb.item_code = '30440'
where tw.name like '%%%%' 
  and ifnull(tw.company, '') in ('', 'TILE SELECT') 
  and tw.is_group = 0.0
order by ifnull(round(tb.actual_qty, 2), 0) desc limit 0, 20
```

Also what is this condition:

```
`tabWarehouse`.`name` like '%%%%'
```

Comment: Hey @forpas , thank you for taking time to answer. I'll try this out and let you know.

Comment: Try it now with a left join of the tables.

Comment: Trying to write the proper query. Actually it's a query with a lot of dynamic variables. I'm a bit confused cz I think you used short forms for the names.

Comment: I used aliases for the 2 tables. Alaises shorten the code and make more readable. `tw` is for tabWarehouse and `tb` is for tabBin.

Comment: There was right parenthesis at the end that I removed and now it is syntactically correct: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gmVv6rF5yRB9tGQEKL6X3E/0

Comment: ```pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from `tabWarehouse` left join `tabBin`\n\t\ton `tabBin`.warehouse = `tabWarehouse`.' at line 3")``` @forpas

Comment: As you can see in the link in my previous comment there is no error now in the query. From the error message you posted I see that you don't use the query as it is so I can't say why you get the error. post the full query.

Comment: This is not sql code. It is Python I suppose where I can't help you. I don't know if you make the correct replacements so the query is syntactically correct. One obvious error you have is that although you use the aliases, you still have ifnull(round(`tabBin`.actual_qty, 2), 0 ) instead of ifnull(round(`tb`.actual_qty, 2), 0 ).

Comment: yeah, I'd replaced it to find out that it was not causing the error..

Comment: The problem is with your Python code that does not produce a syntactically correct query.

Comment: yeah that' my guess also but I can see the actual query in the terminal and not been able to see the wrong.

Comment: Debug the code and check the variable `query` after the formatting.

Comment: I've printed out the query in the terminal but can not see the fault in sql syntax

Comment: `  select tw.name, CONCAT_WS(" : ", "Actual Qty", coalesce(round(tb.actual_qty, 2), 0 ) actual_qty from `tabWarehouse` tw left join `tabBin` tb
on tb.warehouse = tw.name  and tb.item_code = '30440'
where tw.`name` like '%%%%' and coalesce(`tabWarehouse`.company, '') in ('', 'TILE TEST') and `tabWarehouse`.is_group = 0.0 order by coalesce(round(tb.actual_qty, 2), 0) desc limit 0, 20  `

Comment: 2 problems. The 1st is a missing closing parenthesis, change to: `CONCAT_WS(" : ", "Actual Qty", coalesce(round(tb.actual_qty, 2), 0 )) actual_qty` and the 2nd is the use of full table names instead of the aliases in `tabWarehouse.company` and `tabWarehouse.is_group`. Change them to `tw.company` and `tw.is_group` and the query will be fine: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gmVv6rF5yRB9tGQEKL6X3E/1

Answer (score 2):

The `cast` in `select` doesn't change the type of the column -- and the `order by` is referring to the column in the table, not the expression in the `select`.

One option is to give it a new name and use that:

```
select cast(actual_qty as decimal(18,2)) as qty
from `Bin`
where warehouse = `Warehouse`.name
order by qty desc;
```

Or repeat the expression:

```
select cast(actual_qty as decimal(18,2)) as qty
from `Bin`
where warehouse = `Warehouse`.name
order by cast(actual_qty as decimal(18,2)) desc
```